# is there a functional RDP server for Linux? e.g. does FreeRDP actually work as server?

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, vnc, remote-assistance

from wikipedia it is not clear whether there are any legit RDP servers for Linux. Most of what it talks about seems to be alternative / non Microsoft clients intended to communicate with built-in Windows RDP server.

So did anybody out there deal with credible RDP server for Linux? Or are people just happy enough with VNC and TeamViewer for this purpose?

Comment: What distro? Ubuntu / Mint based distros there is a Terminal services server application...

Comment: http://codingdomain.com/linux/remote/x11/

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [xrdp](http://www.xrdp.org/)?

> Based on the work of FreeRDP and rdesktop, xrdp uses the remote
>   desktop protocol to present a GUI to the user.
>
> The goal of this project is to provide a fully functional Linux
>   terminal server, capable of accepting connections from rdesktop,
>   freerdp, and Microsoft's own terminal server / remote desktop clients.
>
> Unlike Windows NT/2000/2003/2008/2012 server, xrdp will not display a
>   Windows desktop but an X window desktop to the user.
>
> Xrdp uses Xvnc or X11rdp to manage the X session.

It is still early in development, but is in a functional state.